# Get Path URL with REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I try get the current path from my page, when I'm using react. My idea is create rules to each pages, because my application need this.

In this 1st sample, I create a component inline and works fine!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const testLink = ({match}) => {
    console.log(match.url)
    return (<h1>Teste {match.params.username} </h1>)
}

class Sponnsor extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
              <Route path="/test/:username" component={testLink} />
            </Router>
            

        );
    }
}
```

I have a correct PATH! (**sample:** /test/john)

But, how I'm not using like this, I could not understand how can I reproduce the **{match}** when I'm in the real component, like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CustomComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            RESULT OF MY PATH
        );
    }
}

export default CustomComponent;
```

I would like, **still reading the current path** and after get this information I will create some condition with my code.

for instance: 
localhost:3000/test/username - path should be: **test/username**

Comment: `render() { console.log(this.props.match); }`

Comment: @riwu I did, and I got this result: test:undefined;
I need import something in my **component**??

Currently I'm importing:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends Component {
   render() { console.log('test:' + this.props.match););}
}

export default Header;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `match` prop is only passed to the component directly specified in `<Route />`, so child components of `TestLink` must be given the `match` prop explicitly.

```
<Route path="/test/:username" component={TestLink} />

const TestLink = ({match}) => {
    console.log(match.url);
    // pass the `match` prop to `CustomComponent`
    return <CustomComponent match={match} />;
}
```

Comment: The solution make sense, thanks man!
But the react complain about: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

`const TestLink = ({match}) => {} // error`
`const TestLink = () => {} // works.`

Looks like, missing import something

Comment: thanks again.

here you can see the code.
[codepen sample](https://codepen.io/c-sar-cabral/pen/XqXzOV?editors=0010)

I have a **Router**, as default. 
many **Route** to navigate.

And the header will control some actions, like: Some buttons will be available at home, others on company page, ....

Comment: The `TestLink` in your code sample is not connected to a `<Route />`? See my example above.

Comment: No, ... I know that is a issue, but I need to find a way to get the current path of my page and send information.

the `TestLink` is a kind of master template, is my header. And this header need to know what is my current path.

I understood what your previews sample, is a <Route>, but in this case, is not a **Route**, but yes a master template, that need receive a current path.

Comment: I see...You can try `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: This works only  on load of page and dont update value. 
any page stay with original path.

Comment: Where's your TestLink located? Is it a PureComponent or connected to redux? Try https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: pureComponent. 
I already try this: withRouter 

but I could not understand where I should add .. in the component  child or parent. I could not also understand how apply using react. 

But thanks a lot anyway man ...

Comment: You can try remove the `Pure` and see if it re-renders when path changes. Otherwise try `withRouter`/redux integration. It's a HOC, wrap the component with it: `class TestLink = .....   export default withRouter(TestLink);`.